# Get value of child radio button using jQuery

Tags: jquery

My HTML code goes like this:

```
   <div id="single"><br><br>
     1) effew<br>
     <input name="answer0" id="answer0" value="1" type="radio"> ewf
     <input name="answer0" id="answer0" value="2" type="radio"> avb
     </div>
     <div id="single"><br><br>
     2) fe<br>
     <input name="answer1" id="answer1" value="1" type="radio"> few
     <input name="answer1" id="answer1" value="2" type="radio"> eww
     <input name="answer1" id="answer1" value="3" type="radio"> tfs
     </div>
```

I want to iterate the above div tags with id as single and then get the value of selected radio button within each div tag with id as single. The jQuery code written is:

```
$("input[name=single]").each( function() {
    var val = $('input[name=answer]:checked').val();
    alert(val);
});
```

The above jQuery code doesn't seem to work. Pls. advice how can I fix it?

Comment: same `id` to multiple elements not allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTML** 
(notice that I changed `Id` by `class` since repeated ids are not allowed

```
 <div class="single"><br><br>
      1) effew<br>
     <input name="answer0" id="answer0" value="1" type="radio"> ewf
     <input name="answer0" id="answer0" value="2" type="radio"> avb
 </div>
 <div class="single"><br><br>
     2) fe<br>
     <input name="answer1" id="answer1" value="1" type="radio"> few
     <input name="answer1" id="answer1" value="2" type="radio"> eww
     <input name="answer1" id="answer1" value="3" type="radio"> tfs
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
$("div.single input[type=radio]:checked").each( function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WtXTs/)

Comment: Cool! Worked for me too!

Answer (score 2):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/NfLwy/

```
$("div.single input:checked").each( function() {
    alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

And the `id` should be unique. Replace maybe with a `class`

Answer (score 0):

Same IDs can't exist on the same html, you should use class in that case.
Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NVhAx/1/). Try it:

**HTML**

```
<div class="single"><br><br>
     1) effew<br>
     <input name="answer0" id="answer0" value="1" type="radio" checked> ewf
     <input name="answer0" id="answer0" value="2" type="radio"> avb
</div>
<div class="single"><br><br>
     2) fe<br>
     <input name="answer1" id="answer1" value="1" type="radio"> few
     <input name="answer1" id="answer1" value="2" type="radio"> eww
     <input name="answer1" id="answer1" value="3" type="radio" checked> tfs
</div>​
```

**JS :**

```
 $("div.single input[type=radio]:checked").each( function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        alert(val);
    });​
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is

```
$('.single').on('click',function(e) {
            alert($($(this).find("input[type=radio]:checked")).attr('id'));
        });
```